# I need to create buttons inside of a already created jTable.

Tags: java, swing

I can't do this with out creating another jtable and It's not what I want the getColumnModel seems to not be working with DefaultModelTable.

it only works if a create a jTable like..
JTable mode = new JTable();
and it's not what I want I want to keep everything in the same window. 
help me!!

class cliente{

```
String t;
String n;
String d;
String m;
String z;
public cliente(String t1, String n1, String d1, String m1, String z1){
this.t = t1;
this.n = n1;
this.d = d1;
this.m = m1;
this.z = z1;
}



public ArrayList getClientListed(){


ArrayList<cliente> clist = new ArrayList<cliente>();
cliente c1 = new cliente(t,n,d,m,z);
clist.add(c1);
return clist;
}
public void showRow(){
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
ArrayList<cliente> clisted = getClientListed();
Object rowdata[] = new Object[5];
for(int i=0; i<clisted.size();i++){
rowdata[0]=clisted.get(i).t;
rowdata[1]=clisted.get(i).n;
rowdata[2]=clisted.get(i).d;
rowdata[3]=clisted.get(i).m;
rowdata[4]=clisted.get(i).z;
model.addRow(rowdata);

    model.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());<-- 

//SET CUSTOM EDITOR TO TEAMS COLUMN
model.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new ButtonEditor(new JTextField()));<-- 
}
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Renderers and editors need to be added to the table, NOT the model.

Comment: thanks it work hahaha thank u!